# Approach to route playback in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-canvas

I am trying to create an Android app that will be able to play back a route I took on some day. I do not want to overlay it on a map when playing back. I want to be able to draw the route on my own choice of canvas (with labels or images of other things relevant to the route for me) and have a dot traveling over that route in play back mode to show my position as time progressed (the labels and images will change as the dot moves, i.e according to context of the dot).

During play back the phone should not use the Internet. During recording, the phone will use GPS to get the lat./long. of my position, at say every second (is this resolution practical?) and store it in a file/database and use that file during playback to construct the route and move the dot. The data for labels and images (from some other file) will be dependent on time (in sec) or position (lat./long.) and would come up on the canvas and/or go off based on the current lat./long. or time of the moving dot.

I want to know the approach I should take to tackle this problem so that I am not digging in wrong areas of the SDK.

I want to know what will be the best file/db to store this kind of information (both for the route points and labels/text and images linked to time and lat./long.) so that it can be read and displayed with route map construction and what kind of graphics libraries to use to achieve my goal.

Comment: As a example - say I am tracking elephants in a forest. As I move along I might take images , videos , enter some text etc. So when playing back I would like the route and my dot over laid on those images , video , even sound etc. And potentially I might want to play back my dot with reference to a previous route I had taken.

Comment: I finally figured it out - please let me know if any one is stuck with the same issue

Comment: How did you solve it.

Comment: :) Oh! god after 11 years ? Can't believe it has been so long. I have to look it up my friend the code must be some where - give me few days time.